# Previous expats with expired Texas license

Tags: driving-license

How does an expat from Ireland returning to work in Texas for a long-term project with a refinery, with an expired TX license, go about renewing or obtaining a current license? Does he have to go through the entire application process again, as though it was his first time to work in TX, or are there some 'shortcuts'?

Answer (score 1):

[This Texas DPS webpage](https://www.dps.texas.gov/DriverLicense/renewal.htm) says Texas drivers license can be renewed up to two years after expiration:

> Most driver licenses and identification cards can be renewed up to two years before and after the expiration date. You have several convenient options to renew your Texas driver license or identification card during this time, including:
>
> - Online
> - By Telephone
> - By Mail
> - In person at your local driver license office

The page goes on to state explicitly that if the applicant's TX license has been expired for more than two years, the license cannot be renewed. The page goes on to describe how those applicants can secure a new TX license, which requires applying as a new applicant with a personal appearance at a drivers license office and new testing.

The DPS site does not mention "exchange" of other states' or countries' drivers license for a Texas license. I conclude such exchange is not permitted.